# Creating html with text overlay on an image with variable position

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am tasked with creating an html document that has a floor plan image as the base layer. Above this I need to overlay employee names that will be pulled out of a database and placed on the map according to a variable in the database named location. Each name will also need to be a hyperlink but I believe this part will be easy once I get the placement down. Additionally when the database is updated with new employees or employees moving. I need to be able to either autosync the page or be able to sync with maybe one click. I have experience with html although this is beyond my current abilities. I also have some experience building windows apps in .net. Can anyone point me to the simplest approach to start tackling this task?

Answer (score 0):

You should check AJAX technology, that will let you to get updated data. Then you should be able to modify positions to new ones.

It's simple and easy with jQuery's $.ajax.

Also if you need realtime updates, check WebSockets.